# How to prevent or avoid control key + click event on anchor tag (href) to open in new TAB, cross browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As i'm trying to prevent to ctr + click event in all the anchor tags in the html application. So can suggest me how to make an effective way to do in all the browsers using javascript or Jquery. Thanks in Advance

```
<a href="myapplication1.html" >myapplication1.html</a>
<a href="myapplication2.html" >myapplication2.html</a>
<a href="myapplication3.html" >myapplication3.html</a>
```

Comment: The question is why do you want to do this? Why do you want to break expected browser behavior? What about mouse wheel click that does the same thing? Contextual menu from right click? What about when the user disables javascript or modifies the page through Dev Tools to restore the behavior you have removed?

Comment: As my application loads the page in the iframe. so when user try to click +ctr key , Page open in new tab, so i do want to prevent this event. But for as i need to disable this event.

Comment: A short answer is: you can't. There are so many ways to open a link in a new tab, and some of them can't be circumvented. As a last resort, user can open a new empty tab, and write the address to the addressbar. You could use a "top-buster", which always opens your pages with the main page. But that's to be written in JS too, your server doesn't know where it is sending the page. Or create a link system, where the links are not actual links, but clicking on them runs a script which shows a new page in the iframe.

Comment: @fekkyDev If you're interested in a simple top-buster, I could post one approach as an answer. That top-buster uses query string in the URL to redirect the iframe, and includes some server-side code too. It's simple to integrate to an existing main page, and doesn't provide changes to the existing links on the main page or subpages. It works well in all modern browsers and IE10 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

I question the wisdom of doing this and some of the comments below support this. FireFox is being very protective when it comes to opening a new tab, and in my opinion rightly so. You need a **VERY** good excuse to break expected browser behavior.

That being said here is a jQuery Approach, that currently works with IE, Edge and Chrome, but *not* Firefox.

```js
//Apply to all a tags
$("a").on("mousedown", function(event){  
  //If middle mouse buton or normal click with ctrl
  if(event.which == 2 || (event.which == 1 && event.ctrlKey)) {  
  console.log("Block");
  //Stop default behavior
  event.preventDefault();
  //Let the user know what is happening and give them options
  if(confirm("Please don't open links in new tabs. Click 'OK' to open the link in this window")){
  //change location of current tab
      window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
  }
  return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.google.com" >Google</a>
<a href="https://www.bing.com" >Bing</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" >Stack Overflow</a>
```

Comment: @Teemu it shouldn't `event.which == 2 ` should handle that.  Testing in chrome and edge seems to work. What browser please?

Comment: FireFox 69, also CTRL + click on a link opens a new tab.

Comment: @Teemu, thx, can't test Firefox in my current environment....some weird IT rules!

Comment: @Teemu, quick favor, I've updated the code to throw a confirm dialog. Does that at least pop in FF69?

Comment: Yep, the pop-up appears, but the default action is not prevented, i.e. the new tabs are still opened, both CTRL + click and middle button open a new tab.

Comment: @Teemu thx, so the event capture works, but `preventDefault` and `return false` not longer work as previous/other browsers

Comment: FireFox has bypassed some key events before, ex. some shortcut key combinations can't be customized with JS. Ignoring tab prevention fits their UX policy well.

Comment: @Teemu, yup, and this just goes to show why what the OP wants to do is folly. It breaks the accepted UX and browser vendors are beginning to get quite picky about that.

Answer (score 0):

Add action listener on all achors detecting the ctrl press

On your template

```html
<a onclick="blockCtrl()">Click Me</a>
```

JS to detect ctrl key press and prevent the action from happening.

```js
function blockCtrl(e){ 
if (window.event.ctrlKey) {
 //ctrl was held down during the click
return false;
 } 
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is a complicated thing to solve. Small research will get you to answer this question. 
However, you can prevent any user action on your page using javascript.
You just have to access the event object. Do as shown below,

```
function blockClick(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.type == "click")
  {
      console.log("ctrl + mouse clicked !")
      e.preventDefault();
  } 
}

<a href="myapplication1.html" onclick="blockClick(event)" >myapplication1.html</a>
<a href="myapplication2.html" onclick="blockClick(event)">myapplication2.html</a>
<a href="myapplication3.html" onclick="blockClick(event)">myapplication3.html</a>
```

This should work. Happy coding.

Comment: Well, that is interesting. It does not work in ie or edge but in other browsers, it works. Let me check and get back to you.